# How to customize the backgorund-color of cancel-button in b-modal?

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-vue

I need to change the background-colour of the cancel-button with rgb. The only half-way up to now is changing the cancel-variant to e.g danger. However, I need to choose the specific, rgb colour. Does anyone know a solution to my problem?
Thank you

```
<b-modal v-bind:id="'delete-modal-' + id" cancel-variant=info ok-variant=danger ok-title="delete" cancel-title="back" @ok="deleteModal" title="Caution">
  <p class="my-4">Are you sure?</p>
</b-modal>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using SASS you can easily add new variants to your project by adding them to the `$theme-colors` map.
These will automatically become available to use with bootstrap-vue everywhere you can use a variant.

`custom.scss`

```css
$theme-colors: (
  "cancel": rgb(139, 80, 80)
);

@import 'node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
@import 'node_modules/bootstrap-vue/src/index.scss';
```

Then import `custom.scss` in your apps entry point.

If you want a simple CSS solution, the `cancel-variant` property just adds the class `btn-*` where * is the string you provide.

Which means you can add the css below to your global stylesheet, to add a new variant (however, doing it this way you'll have to write all the :hover, :active stuff yourself)

```css
.btn-cancel {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: rgb(213, 213, 213);
  border-color: rgb(213, 213, 213);
}
```

After adding one of the options above you will now have the option to do `<b-modal cancel-variant="cancel"></b-modal>` to utilize your new variant.